# How to delete all content of input.txt file after instance.save()?

Tags: python

```
text = "sample sample"
text_file = open("input.txt", "r+b")
text_file.write(text)
instance.src_after = File(text_file)
instance.save()
text_file.close()
```

How to delete all content of `input.txt` file after `instance.save()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `file.truncate`:

```
text_file.truncate(0)
```

help on `file.truncate`:

```
>>> print file.truncate.__doc__
truncate([size]) -> None.  Truncate the file to at most size bytes.

Size defaults to the current file position, as returned by tell().
```